# Do molecules like NH2 cation exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions

I saw that the book said that nitrogen cations must have four bonds and no lone pairs. I wasn't sure why you couldn't have a lone pair and 2 bonds.

Comment: If the nitrogen atom has one lone pair, it must have THREE bonds. So can you revise your question?

Comment: Nitrogen must satisfy the octet rule; having one lone pair and two bonds would be too unstable.

Comment: How could it have a lone pair and three bonds if the nitrogen has a positive formal charge? @SteffX

Comment: On a similar note, why is it that oxygen with a negative formal charge may have 1 bond and 3 lone pairs? I'm struggling with this concept to determine what the appropriate amount of bonds and lone pairs are. Why couldn't a negative oxygen have 3 bonds and 2 lone pairs? Wouldn't you still have 7 electrons? I feel like I'm missing a pretty important concept. @a-cyclohexane-molecule

Comment: Oxygen must also satisfy the *octet rule*: there must be eight electrons associated with each oxygen atom, either through lone pairs or bonds. With respect to bonds, both electrons in a bond count toward the eight electrons, as opposed to a formal-charge calculation, where only one contributes.

Comment: Such cations are called [nitrenium ions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrenium_ion) and are very reactive.

Comment: Please cite your source.

Comment: The radical NH$_2\cdot$ is also known. It  has C$_{2v}$ symmetry and has been studied in the gas phase. It has an absorption spectrum from 900 to 400 nm.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mithoron said, $\ce{NH2+}$ ion is called [parent nitrenium ion.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrenium_ion) The following text is an abstract from a paper<sup>1</sup> which discussed its generation and various trapping pathways:

> **[...] (It) has been generated in various solutions through photolysis of 1-amino-2,4,6-triphenylpyridinium perchlorate.** It was
> found that the hydrocarbons, toluene and triphenylmethane trap
> $\ce{NH2+}$ through two independent pathways. (1) free radical pathway
> which leads to bibenzyl (in the case of toluene) or the trityl radical
> (in the case of triphenylmethane). (2) hydride transfer
> pathway which leads to benzyltoluene (in the case of toluene) or
> triphenylmethanol (in the case of triphenylmethane). Results from dilution, triplet sensitization, and EPR experiments lead to the assignment of the hydride transfer pathway  to the singlet state of $\ce{NH2+}$ and the radical pathway to the triplet state of $\ce{NH2+}$ [...]
>
> $$\ce{PhCH2+ + NH3 <-[PhCH3] ^{1}NH2+ -> ^{3}NH2+ ->[PhCH3] NH3+^{.} + PhCH2. }$$

There is also another paper<sup>2</sup> which discuss about the reaction of $\ce{NH+, NH2+}$, and $\ce{NH3+}$ ions with $\ce{H2}$ at low temperatures which leads to formation of ammonium ions (the general pathway of $\ce{NH4+}$ generation in interstellar environment):

$$\ce{N+ ->[H2] NH+ ->[H2] NH2+ ->[H2] NH3+ ->[H2] NH4+}$$

This reaction scheme is very much temperature dependent as it can lead to different pathways. For instance, reaction between $\ce{NH+}$ and $\ce{H2}$ has two pathways:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{NH+ + H2 &->[k^{a}_{NH^{+}}] NH2+ + H} &\quad \Delta H^{\circ} = \pu{-1.9 eV}  & \tag{1}\\
\ce{NH+ + H2 &->[k^{b}_{NH^{+}}] H3+ + N} &\quad \Delta H^{\circ} = \pu{-0.8 eV} & \tag{2}\\
\end{align}
$$

The former pathway occurs at 300 K while the latter one occurs at 15 K.

**Reference**

1. On the Solution Chemistry of Parent Nitrenium Ion NH2+:  The Role of
   the Singlet and Triplet States in Its Reactions with Water,
   Methanol, and Hydrocarbons Sanjay Srivastava, Michael Kercher, and
   Daniel E. Falvey The Journal of Organic Chemistry **1999** 64 (16),
   5853-5857 DOI: [10.1021/jo990324+](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jo990324%2B)
2. Reaction of NH+, NH2+, and NH3+ ions with H2 at low temperatures
   The pathway to ammonia production in the interstellar medium
   S. Rednyk, Š. Roučka, A. Kovalenko, T. D. Tran, P. Dohnal, R. Plašil and J. Glosík, A&A
   Volume 625, **2019**, DOI: [10.1051/0004-6361/201834149](https://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2019/05/aa34149-18/aa34149-18.html)